# Help with Drupal upgrade

Tags: drupal, upgrade, php

I currently use Drupal 7.5.3 and need to upgrade to 7.5.4. Running it with CiviCRM. I'm a novice with this site and need a little hand holding to figure this out. Basically the site admin is AWOL and the person running the organization I'm working for asked me to figure this out.

I used instructions from here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7#UpgradingCiviCRMforDrupal7-1.DownloadthemostrecentCiviCRMPackage

I'm stuck at steps 7 through 11, since I don't know where the code files are stored or how to access them.

Comment: Minor, but important point. I presume that you mean upgrade Drupal 7.53 to 7.54.  There isn't a Drupal 7.5.3 or 7.5.4.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1) The instructions you posted are for a CiviCRM upgrade, not a Drupal upgrade.

2) There's nothing wrong with being a novice!  However, upgrading a live site is something you do NOT want to take on without some experience, much as you wouldn't try to fix your house's electricity without some practice.  You can easily wreck the site - upgrades are NOT something you can do via point-and-click on the website.

If after reading this you're interested in learning the skills, I would try installing Drupal on your personal computer, following one of the many tutorials available online.  It will be challenging - expect to take at least a day if you're inexperienced!  When you're done, you'll be in a much better position to tackle your live site.

Comment: You can find instructions for how to upgrade Drupal here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1223018